# when do i need a larger bulk_insert_buffer_size

Tags: mysql, insert

I uses "load data ..." to load large datas to mysql, and set key_buffer_size to a very large size (32G).
and for now, I find inserting is not fast as i assume, and i set bulk_insert_buffer_size to 32M.

I uses mysqltuner.pl and some-like scripts to find out if i need to change some value of variables, but how can i decide that i need a larger bulk_insert_buffer_size? Or, can I find out how much size mysql used?

BTW, in doc, it says that: "This variable limits the size of the cache tree in bytes **per thread**". So if i uses 10 connections for inserting, will it take 10*bulk_insert_buffer_size memory ?